# How to plot a 2D vector field on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plot, vector, graph

I have not been able to find a way to plot a vector field on ruby on rails. I want to introduce 2 parameters and a simple function and obtain something like this:[vector field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCtP8.png)

In case that it is not possible, is there away to plot a simple arrow on XY axis like this:
[single vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S10qP.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Need more detail, are you trying to draw things in the browser, or a PDF, or what?

Comment: In the browser.

Comment: Alright, well in that case you're going to want to do it with Javascript. Rails doesn't really have this kind of functionality. It can get your data _into_ the browser but in terms of how you display it - Rails doesn't really care. Spend a bit of time to learn HTML5 Canvas, and you'll be able to do this.

Comment: You can also very easily find Javascript libraries to draw graphs for example [d3](https://d3js.org/).